# Grep fail to ouptut to a pipe?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, unix, shell

I'm having problems with grep filtering of make output. In particular,

```
make target 2>&1 | grep -E --color=never "^make.*"
```

works as expected, but the following will print no output to the console:

```
make target 2>&1 | grep -E --color=never "^make.*" | cat
```

Am I missing something obvious? Why does the first command output but not the second? Is it to do  with some sort of IO buffering? Or am I just being stupid?

**[EDIT]:** `cat` is just a minimum test case placeholder for the actual command I want to use.

**[EDIT]:** This does not seem to be a problem with grep, as replacing it with [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/) leads to the same behaviour.

**[EDIT]:** Script that cat is a placeholder for:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat - \
 | grep -E --color=never "^.*warning:.*|^.*error:.*|^make.*[Ee]rror.*|^make.*" \
 | hilite.sh -r "^.*warning:.*" -f yellow -B \
 | hilite.sh -r "^.*error:.*" -f red -B \
 | hilite.sh -r "^make.*[Ee]rror.*" -f red -B \
 | hilite.sh -r "^make.*" -f magenta
```

**[EDIT]:** I think it's a buffering/IO issue. I'm leaving the build running over the w/e and will see if it eventually gets the output where it needs to!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Likely `grep` is detecting that it's not writing to a TTY, so it buffers more output, rather than operating in its usual line buffered mode (i.e. you see each line as it's found). This behavior is more efficient as it results in fewer `write()` system calls, but if you're a user who's waiting for pipelined output, then it may be a bit misleading.

If you're using GNU `grep` (and based on your linux tag I'm assuming you are), check out the `--line-buffered` option, which will force `grep` to work in the more familiar line buffered mode.  This could technically decrease the performance of `grep` (as noted in the man page), but since you're looking at the output of a live build, I doubt it will make any difference in that regard.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your command is supposed to do, cat any files that have make.* in their file name?

Try changing the `cat` for `xargs cat`?

Comment: Cat is just a placeholder for another set of commands. It fails to output anything regardless of what I replace it with.

Comment: then try cat \`make target 2>&1 | grep -E --color=never "^make.*"\`

Comment: That didn't help. (aside: the make command takes several minutes)

Comment: What about if you turned it into a for loop? `for file in \`make target 2>&1 | grep -E --color=never "^make.*"\`; do cat $file; done`

Comment: Javano: I'm actually trying to build a highlighting filter for make, rather than do something with the filename. I'm not iterating over lines as much as editing a bytestream. (besides the fact that make output could not be used like this. I've added the script that I use instead of cat for you to get an idea of what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

You might try experimenting with `unbuffer`, e.g.,

```
make target 2>&1 | unbuffer -p grep -E --color=never "^make.*" | cat
```

Comment: I'd not heard of unbuffer before. I'll check it out. it could come in handy.